# Context needed for SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-context

I am using SharedPreferences in my asynctask but because of this the following line of code does not work:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

But if I remove the 'this.' it throws me this error:

```
09-04 10:16:49.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:161)
```

Also, it is being called from a service if that complicates things anymore? So how do I provide proper context to this SharedPreferences?

Comment: use class this that extends Activity like MainActivity.this

Comment: Ps: you should include the entire error you get without the `this`.

Comment: You only need the application's context to access to a SharedPreference. If you need it from outside an Activity I would suggest that you create an Application class and use the context from there when you need.

Ah! And the Service has its own context - you can use it.

Comment: create global variable for `Context` and use this `context` in whole activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a parameter in the AsyncTask Constructor, that will be the base context, like it:

```
public class X extends AsyncTask {

    private Context context;

    public X(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    doInBackground() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // your code
    }
```

Hugs.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it globally in class which extends Activity

```
 public static SharedPreferences prefs;
   pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

Now u can use `pref` as per your need.

Comment: That is a good point too, +1 for alternate answer that works :)